# Entity Exception was unhandled by user code in Global.asax

Tags: global-asax, redirect-loop

I'm using a Microsoft sample project for entity framework code first;"WingtipToys". All I did was extracting the file and opening the solution. The project got built successfully but I got an error while running the website. It stops in a line in Global.asax and the message is: **Entity Exception was unhandled by user code** "**The underlying provider failed on Open**". Surprisingly, I used this sample project couple of days ago and it worked fine but all of sudden this error happened even though, I didnt change anything in the code and now even with a fresh downloaded copy I get the same issue.

By the way, when I browse any webpages by google Chrome I get this error message. 
"This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://"Serveraddress"/ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer."

public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
            Database.SetInitializer(new ProductDatabaseInitializer());

```
        // Add Administrator.
        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator")) --- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Error at this line
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        }
        if (Membership.GetUser("Admin") == null)
        {
            Membership.CreateUser("Admin", "Pa$$word", "Admin@contoso.com");
            Roles.AddUserToRole("Admin", "Administrator");
```

and below is exception details
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=Cannot open database "aspnet-WingtipToys" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Jinx-PC\Jinx'.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=11
       LineNumber=65536
       Number=4060
       Procedure=""
       Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0
       State=1
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
       InnerException: